# Beautfil Soup Error with simple script

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am running Beautiful Soup 4.5 with Python 3.4 on Windows 7.  Here is my script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url = 'https://scholar.google.com'
response = http.request('GET', url)
html2 = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup([html2])

print (type(soup))
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> TypeError: Expected String or Buffer

I have researched and there seem to be no fixes except going to an older version of Beautiful Soup which I don't want to do.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why are you putting the html string into the list here:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup([html2])
```

Replace it with:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html2)
```

Or, you can also pass the response file-like object, `BeautifulSoup` would read it for you:

```
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
```

---

It is also a good idea to *specify a parser explicitly*:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html2, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I tried that but I guess not, because that got rid of the error message.